# Replace the values of a column of an array in a for loop Python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, for-loop, matrix

I have a 3D array of zeros and I would like, using a for loop, to replace the elements of the second and third column.
In matlab i created a zeros matrix and fill it, but in python i don't understand how can i do it.

I tried the following way:

```
U=np.zeros((3,150,150))
step=10
A=[rows,columns]
jj=0
    for j in range(1,columns+1,step):
        jj=jj+1 #jj total = 184
    

         ii=0
         for i in range(1,rows+1,step):        
             ii=ii+1  #ii total = 154


             U[:,0,1]=ii,jj
```

In this way, I get an array U where, each value of the second and third column have the values of the last one ii and jj.

Instead, I would like each pixel(i,j) present in array A to be progressively replaced in the second and third column of array U, following the defined step.
Do you have any idea about it?

the array U, in the end, will have size (3x154x184)

Answer (score 0):

This code will put the values of A into U in a for loop. If you have other logic to use, you can add it in the skipped lines.

```
import numpy as np

columns = 150
rows = 150
step=1
A=np.random.randint(100, size=(columns,rows))
U=np.zeros((3,columns,rows))

jj=0
for j in range(0,columns,step):
    jj=jj+1 #jj total = 184
    
    
    ii=0
    for i in range(0,rows,step):        
        ii=ii+1  #ii total = 154
        
        U[:,ii-1,jj-1]=A[i,j]

print(U)
```

If that is all you are trying to accomplish, you can do it much more simply like this:

```
U[:]=A
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Your advice solves the problem partially, because i get an array of size (3x150,150).

A is an 2D array (1540x1838).
U should be an 3D array (3,154,184).

If i use U[:]=A, i get:ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (1540,1838) into shape (3,150,150)